# Disable Builtin Rules from sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

I need to Disable the builtin rules which is present in SonarQube
It is throwing many bugs because of the below rule

I tried removing it , since it is a builtin rule i could not find any option for removing the rule

```
<strong> and <em> tags should be used -> it is considered as a bug in sonarqube
```

Please provide the solution for removing the above rule from the rule list of the sonarqube of my project

Answer (score 1):

You can not deactivate rule in a built-in profile. You will need to create your own quality profile (click on Quality Profile menu). Once you have your own quality profile you can activate/deactivate/customize rules at will.

Don't forget to associate the profile with your project or set it as a default afterwards.

Comment: I could not find any option like create or add in Quality Profile Menu
can you guide me where i can able to create the custom rules and associate it to my project